# Integrated Elasticsearch with acts_as_paranoid gem with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter out all deleted records (using paranoid gem https://github.com/goncalossilva/acts_as_paranoid) out of Elasticsearch result.

The `acts_as_paranoid` is soft delete, this gem will override the `destroy` method for our model, it added a column name `deleted_at (datetime)` in our model, and set nil if this record isn't deleted.
And in Elasticsearch, I wanna filter out (all deleted records should not appear in the 
search result), but I still get them.

Here is my code in elasticsearch:

```
  tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: per_page) do
    query do
      boolean do
        must { term: {"deleted_at": nil} }
      end
      filter :range, created_at: {gte: params[:created_after]} if params[:created_after]
      filter :term, city: CITIES[params[:city]] unless CITIES[params[:city]].blank?
      sort do
        by :created_at, "desc"
      end
     end
   end
```

And also I had tried to put `filter :missing, field: :deleted_at`

But it didn't work correctly. 
Please show me what is my mistake(s) and how can I fixed it? It make me crazy @@

Comment: Is the field deleted_at indexed in elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes, I use ```date``` type for deleted_at. Is it OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the index first and create it again, maybe your data is affected by the index before using soft delete.

**STEP 1: Drop the index**

```
bundle exec rake environment tire:index:drop force=true INDICES=<index_name>
```

**STEP 2: Create the index again**

```
bundle exec rake environment tire:import:all force=true
```

Using `http://localhost:9200/_aliases` to check for `<index_name>` (INDICES's value)

Comment: I don't understand, my indexes is existed before I started to use soft delete gem.
But what is the problem here? Can you explain to me?

Comment: Now I understand, You added the gem after creating the indices. But the index doesn't have the mapping details regarding deleted_at. As the deleted_at is a new field you could have tried just the import all option without force option. Even that should have worked. As new fields get dynamically mapped into index. So, doing a reindex will create the index with new mapping settings. The new mapping will have deleted_at. So, the filter will work without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to look into:

Is the field deleted_at indexed?

If yes, your filter solution should work or else

1. Clean all the documents with deleted_at and then you have to clean up the document from elasticsearch whenever there is a soft delete
2. you need to add the deleted_at in the index and then use this filter.

If you want to go for step 1 you can use this piece of code:

I see that you are using **tire ruby client** to connect to elasticsearch:

Get the ids of the documents which have deleted_at NOT set to nil

something like the below piece of code should work

```
<Modelname>.all.map {|i| i.id if !usr.deleted_at.nil?}.compact #This is just an example no tests have been run to test the performance to fetch thousands of records.
```

You can use something else. All you need is **Get the ids of the documents which have deleted_at NOT set to nil**

Then use the below code to remove those documents from elasticsearch.

```
id_array = [1,2,3]
query = Tire.search do |search|
        search.query { |q| q.terms :_id, id_array }
      end

index = Tire.index('<index_name>') # provide the index name as you have in your code

Tire::Configuration.client.delete "#{index.url}/_query?source=#{Tire::Utils.escape(query.to_hash[:query].to_json)}"
```

Once this is done you have to use the same code whenever there is a soft delete. Instead of an array of numbers you can just send a single id in the array or you can use the term filter instead of terms to send single id

**For single document:**

```
id_no = 1
query = Tire.search do |search|
        search.query { |q| q.term :_id, id_no }
      end

index = Tire.index('<index_name>') # provide the index name as you have in your code

Tire::Configuration.client.delete "#{index.url}/_query?source=#{Tire::Utils.escape(query.to_hash[:query].to_json)}"
```

If you want to go for step 2, add deleted_at in your to_indexed_json and then reindex your data and then use the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had tried it. But it seems useless for me.
I had tried @nguyentrinhhongngoc 's answer, it works but I do not understand why. Can you explain this?

Comment: My first statement **Is the field deleted_at indexed? If yes, your filter solution should work or else** says that you need to go for this option if it is not indexed. As you said its added in the index, the above solution doesn't hold good.